# Bash: pop lines in a file

Tags: bash, line

I need to read a file with bash and remove the request line? Some similar to 
pop/push functions.

How can i do it?

Comment: some sample input data and expected output would help us provide a better answer.

Comment: How big is this file? (this is important because 'in-place' methods, for example using `sed -i` could be dangerous if the file is large). Also, are you popping/pushing to the front, back or middle of the file?

Comment: @LeeNetherton, How could `sed` be *dangerous if the file is large*? I've alredy processed mysql's dumps upto 7Gb with something like `gunzip | sed | gzip`.

Comment: Depending on what you are set out to accomplish, moving / removing entire files in a queue directory hierarchy may be more robust.

Comment: @F. Hauri: in-place editing could produce unpredictable results if multiple processes attempt to do it at the same time, on the same file. The file's size isn't really the issue, but with larger files you are likely to hit race conditions more often.

Comment: @tripleee Of course, concurrent editing directly on fs is not a good idea, but this is not a concern about *big files*. Lee stat that *sed could be dangerous if the file is large*, at my knowledge, that's not true. `sed` is very robust, efficient and stable.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have misread the comment.

Comment: @F. Hauri: Actually, using `sed -i` could be more dangerous with large files, not because of the increased risk of a race condition, but because of problems caused by lack of disk space -- see the '-i' option here: http://www.ipnom.com/FreeBSD-Man-Pages/sed.1.html Of course, this 'danger' can easily be circumvented by using a backup extension as the optional argument, e.g. `sed -i~`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` to delete specific line numbers or lines that match a given pattern:

```
$ cat file
line 1
line 2 
line 3 
line 4
line 5

$ sed -i '3d' file             # Delete the 3rd line
line 1
line 2 
line 4
line 5    

$ sed -i '/^line 4$/d' file    # Delete the line that matches the pattern
line 1
line 2 
line 3 
line 5


$ sed '$d' file                # Delete the last line in the file
line 1
line 2 
line 3 
line 4
```

You will not be able to `push` these lines back however..

Answer (score 16):

### Right! `sed` would do the job finely!

#### Intro

As rightly pointed by a comment from [@Lee Netherton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341459/lee-netherton), the when running [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) for *inplace* editing, the use of backups are **strongly** recommended! (Of course, once done, your script have to test the success of `sed` command before continuing... )

#### Test case

So let quickly build a test file:

```
printf "Line #%2d\n" {1..7} >file
```

#### for *pop* (from top of stack):

As a *real push/pop*, the following command return the wanted line **and** drop them from the named file.

```
sed -e \$$'{w/dev/stdout\n;d}' -i~ file
Line # 7
```

then

```
cat file
Line # 1
Line # 2
Line # 3
Line # 4
Line # 5
Line # 6
```

#### for *shift* (from bottom of stack):

```
sed -e 1$'{w/dev/stdout\n;d}' -i~ file
Line # 1
```

#### for *splice* (random access in stack)

(removing **n**th line)

```
lineNum=3
sed -e $lineNum$'{w/dev/stdout\n;d}' -i~ file
Line # 4
```

#### for *push* (to top of stack):

```
printf -v val "Line #%2d" 28
echo "$val" >>file
```

Nota: This could be done by using `sed` anyway:

```
sed -e "\$a$val" -i~ file
```

(Where `$a` IS NOT a variable, but the *sed* location `$`, which mean *at end of file* and the `a` command, which mean *append after current line*)

#### for *unshift* (to bottom of stack):

```
printf -v val "Line #%2d" 62
sed -e 1i"$val" -i~ file
```

Then finally

```
cat file
Line #62
Line # 2
Line # 3
Line # 5
Line # 6
Line #28
```

#### Into a variable

Of course, the goal is to retrieve them into a variable. Depending of if you are using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) or another *POSIX* [shell](/questions/tagged/shell), you could use one of:

```
lastline=`sed -e \\\$$'{w/dev/stdout\n;d}' -i~ file`
echo $lastline 
Line #28

lastline=$(sed -e \$$'{w/dev/stdout\n;d}' -i~ file)
echo $lastline 
Line # 6

read lastline < <(sed -e \$$'{w/dev/stdout\n;d}' -i~ file)
echo $lastline 
Line # 5
```

### Added for new year 2018

**Happy new year!**

#### Sample, simple bash functions:

```
fpop() { local v n=$'\n';read -r v < <(
    sed -e $'${w/dev/stdout\n;d}' -i~ "$1")
    printf ${2+-v} $2 "%s${n[${2+2}]}" "$v"
}
fshift() { local v n=$'\n';read -r v < <(
    sed -e $'1{w/dev/stdout\n;d}' -i~ "$1")
    printf ${2+-v} $2 "%s${n[${2+2}]}" "$v"
}
fsplice() {
    [ "$2" ] || return ; local v n=$'\n';read -r v < <(
    sed -e $2$'{w/dev/stdout\n;d}' -i~ "$1");
    printf ${3+-v} $3 "%s${n[${3+3}]}" "$v"
}
fpush() { sed -e "\$a$2" -i~ "$1"; }
funshift() { sed -e "1i$2" -i~ "$1"; }
```

Nota: Line `printf ${2+-v} $2 "%s${n[${2+2}]}" "$v"` is a kind of *trick* I use often in my functions. This line will populate a variable, if submited as second argument. If else this line will add a *newline* and print to *`STDOUT`*.

Little run sample:

```
printf "Line #%2d\n" {3..12} >file   

fpop file
Line #12
fpop file myvar
echo $myvar
Line #11

fshift file
Line # 3
fshift file myvar
echo $myvar
Line # 4

fsplice file 3 
Line # 7
fsplice file 3 myvar
echo $myvar
Line # 8

funshift file "Line # 192"
fpush file "Line # 42"

cat file
Line # 192
Line # 5
Line # 6
Line # 9
Line #10
Line # 42

declare -p myvar
declare -- myvar="Line # 8"
```

(The variable *myvar* didn't contain *newline*.)

And ( I can't resist! ;-):

```
fpop file myvar
echo $((9? ${myvar#*#} :-b))
42
```

Comment: Thank you for a great solution. If case anyone needs a PHP shell_exec version of the command, which works on both bash and dash, here it goes: ` \`sed -e \\\$'{w/dev/stdout\nd}' -i~ $strFile\` `. Backtick works like a double quote in PHP, negating the need for the Bash $ expansion in order to get \n to become lf.

Comment: If I may ask, why is unshift more complicated than `echo "$line" >> "$file"` ?

Comment: I've used `sed $a ...` instead of `echo >>` just to keep using `sed` for all functions. But of course, `cat >> "$file" <<<"$line"` will work too!

Answer (score 1):

sed is orient to stream, you can use ed which suit edit file.

```
#/usr/bin/sh

ed -s filename <<EDSCRIPT
1p
d
wq
EDSCRIPT
```

1. print first line to stdout.
2. delete it.
3. save it and quit.

if you want to do other things, 
`1,3` is for line 1 to line 3. 
`$` is for last line.